# Cannot write to ARM register R4: feature or bug?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, assembly, cortex-a8

I've recently encountered a strange behaviour of ARM Cortex-A8 when programming it in Assembly. Whenever I `MOV` anything into R4, my program crashes (stack dump below)

```
10-14 09:48:43.117: INFO/DEBUG(3048): Build fingerprint: 'google/soju/crespo:2.3.6/GRK39F/189904:user/release-keys'
10-14 09:48:43.121: INFO/DEBUG(3048): pid: 7082, tid: 7082  >>> neontests <<<
10-14 09:48:43.121: INFO/DEBUG(3048): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000001
10-14 09:48:43.125: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  r0 00000001  r1 afa025b6  r2 00000000  r3 bec77051
10-14 09:48:43.128: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  r4 00000001  r5 bec7704c  r6 00000001  r7 00000004
10-14 09:48:43.128: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  r8 00000005  r9 00000000  10 4214cca4  fp 800a5368
10-14 09:48:43.128: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  ip afa03110  sp bec77010  lr afa0133b  pc afd37b42  cpsr 60000030
10-14 09:48:43.132: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d0  0000000200000053  d1  0000000400000074
10-14 09:48:43.132: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d2  000000060000006f  d3  0000000800000070
10-14 09:48:43.132: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d4  006f0065006e002e  d5  007300650074006e
10-14 09:48:43.136: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d6  0000000c00000005  d7  0000002000000015
10-14 09:48:43.136: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d8  0000000c00000005  d9  0000002000000015
10-14 09:48:43.140: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.140: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.140: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.144: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d16 800220e8401644a8  d17 bff0000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.144: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d18 3ff0000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.148: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.148: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d22 3ff0000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.148: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.148: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.148: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.148: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
10-14 09:48:43.148: INFO/DEBUG(3048):  scr 20000012
10-14 09:48:43.195: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #00  pc 00037b42  /system/lib/libc.so
10-14 09:48:43.195: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #01  pc 00001338  /system/lib/liblog.so
10-14 09:48:43.199: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #02  pc 00001482  /system/lib/liblog.so
10-14 09:48:43.199: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #03  pc 00000c54  /data/data/neontests/lib/libneon_tests.so
10-14 09:48:43.199: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #04  pc 00017e34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.199: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #05  pc 0004968c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.199: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #06  pc 0004ee62  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.199: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #07  pc 0001d034  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.199: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #08  pc 000220e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.199: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #09  pc 00020fdc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.199: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #10  pc 0005fdde  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.203: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #11  pc 00067b52  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.203: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #12  pc 0001d034  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.203: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #13  pc 000220e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.203: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #14  pc 00020fdc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.203: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #15  pc 0005fc40  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.203: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #16  pc 0004c126  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-14 09:48:43.203: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #17  pc 00032572  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
10-14 09:48:43.203: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #18  pc 0003341e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
10-14 09:48:43.203: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #19  pc 00008cca  /system/bin/app_process
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):          #20  pc 00014b52  /system/lib/libc.so
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): code around pc:
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afd37b20 18801889 c003f810 c003f801 d2f93b01 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afd37b30 bf00bdf0 2200b510 3201e003 4618b90b 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afd37b40 5c83e004 42a35c8c 1b18d0f7 bf00bd10 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afd37b50 b152b530 5cc42300 42ac5ccd 1b60d001 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afd37b60 b114e004 429a3301 2000d1f5 bf00bd30 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): code around lr:
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afa01318 fffffff4 00001e20 b088b570 4615460c 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afa01328 b9099001 447c4c28 46204928 f7ff4479 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afa01338 2800edc4 4926d02e 22034620 f7ff4479 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afa01348 b338edc2 46204923 f7ff4479 b308edb6 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): afa01358 46204921 f7ff4479 b1d8edb0 4620491f 
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048): stack:
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76fd0  800a5368  
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76fd4  afd1c701  /system/lib/libc.so
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76fd8  bec771f0  
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76fdc  bec77051  
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76fe0  0000ce60  
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76fe4  000003fa  
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76fe8  ffff0208  
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76fec  bec7704c  
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76ff0  000003ff  
10-14 09:48:43.207: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76ff4  00000000  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76ff8  00000003  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec76ffc  00000004  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77000  80400d90  /data/data/neontests/lib/libneon_tests.so
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77004  bec7704c  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77008  df002777  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec7700c  e3a070ad  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048): #00 bec77010  00000001  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77014  afa0133b  /system/lib/liblog.so
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048): #01 bec77018  80400420  /data/data/neontests/lib/libneon_tests.so
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec7701c  00000004  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77020  bec7701c  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77024  00000001  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77028  80400d90  /data/data/neontests/lib/libneon_tests.so
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec7702c  00000014  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77030  00000000  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77034  00000000  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77038  bec7704c  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec7703c  afd4d5c8  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77040  00000001  
10-14 09:48:43.210: INFO/DEBUG(3048):     bec77044  afa01487  /system/lib/liblog.so
```

*Edit*: Stack dump above is the result of the following code (apologies, GNU Assembly highlighting seems to be a bit odd here):

```
.arm
.global asm_test

asm_test:

    mov r0, #4 @make sure r0 is not the same as r4   
    mov r4, #1 @move to r4 something different from r0

    mov pc, lr @return from function
```

I'm calling it from (native) C as follows:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arm_neon.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "com_something_neontests_NativeLib.h"

extern volatile int asm_test(void);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_something_neontests_NativeLib_asmTry
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "com.something.neontests", "Start!");

    asm_test();

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "com.something.neontests", "Done!");


    return 0;
}
```

Here are a few things I notice. First, whenever I assign anything to R4, be it `MOV R4, #2` or `ADD R4, R0, R1`, the result *does* end up in R4 before the program crashes, but the same result also always ends up in R0. I also found out that I can `POP` stuff from the stack into R4. No other registers exhibit this same behaviour. Assembly code compiles using Android NDK, which I believe uses GCC 4.4.3. I tested it on several Android phones and everything seems to be consistent.

I know that all registers are sectioned such that R0-R3 take in arguments, R4-R12 are variable registers, then there are special registers and so on. Perhaps this behaviour is caused by some sort of C calling convention I've never heard about? Is there an explanation for this, is it expected?

Cheers! = )

***Update***:

As @Graham kindly pointed out, r4 (alternatively v1) is a variable register which should be preserved. However, in the [link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/ch06s02s01.html) provided in his answer, ARM documentation itself makes use of the v1 register, by first saving its result on the stack along with value of another preserved register:

```
STMDB sp!,{v1,lr}
LDR v1,[a2,#0]
```

and later retrieving their values. When I compile this code, it crashes the same way as my original, but

```
STMDB sp!,{v1,lr}
LDR v2,[a2,#0]
```

doesn't (notice v2 instead of v1).

Comment: Could you show the smallest possible code that's crashing? `fault addr 00000001` seems to suggest that you're loading from the address contained in `r4`. The same result showing up in `r0` sounds odd.

Comment: I still get the feeling that we're not shown all the relevant code. Do you have a self contained example that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: @user786653 There is no other code. I am calling it from C using Android Native interfaces. If that's relevant, I can post my C function as well.

Comment: Yes, please do that and all of the code you're using to store and retrieve `v1` (a simple typo could be the cause).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4271/discussion-between-user786653-and-phonon)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What we are trying to explain is that you need to do this if you want to use r4 in a function:

```
.globl asm_test
asm_test:
    stmdb r13!,{r4}
    mov r0, #4 @make sure r0 is not the same as r4
    mov r4, #1 @move to r4 something different from r0
    ldmia r13!,{r4}
    mov pc, lr @return from function
```

Otherwise you leave a time bomb that goes off at some point down the road.  The compiler has allocated r4 for something in a higher level function, and by the rules nobody can change that register so that higher level call does not have to protect r4, by messing it up at the right time and place you create the problem, how the problem behaves is code dependent.  And will explain why other registers, in this case, are not sensitive.  Sometimes when you do this you wont actually crash, sometimes perhaps a string is printed wrong or a loop repeats itself or exits early.

To see what is going on please disassemble the function in question (not the source code but a disassembly).  plus the functions that called it and the functions that called that until r4 shows up in one of those surrounding functions.  examine what r4 is being used for.

You can also change the behavior if your asm_test() calling function were to have local variables that are used before and after the asm_test() call in such a way that the optimizer keeps them in registers, but also such that the optimizer does not remove the code all together:

```
void fun ( void )
{
  int r;
  r=10;
  asm_test();
  r++;
}
```

The optimizer would completely remove r in the above code, but:

```
int fun ( int a, int b, int c, int d )
{
   int e;
   e=a+b+c+d;
   b=asm_test(a+d);
   e+=b; 
   return(e);
}
```

creates more than enough to force the compiler to build a stack frame.

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e0811000    add r1, r1, r0
   4:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   8:   e0830000    add r0, r3, r0
   c:   e0814002    add r4, r1, r2
  10:   e0844003    add r4, r4, r3
  14:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <asm_test>
  18:   e0840000    add r0, r4, r0
  1c:   e8bd8010    pop {r4, pc}
```

r4 is the variable e in this case (around the asm_test call) and by messing up r4 you will change what the function fun() returns.  If that value were never used on the call to fun for example your modification of r4 would go unnoticed.

The compilers follow the calling convention rules and expect all callees to as well, if you mess with that the ways that it can crash/fail go from no effect to quite serious, so you need to conform to those calling conventions in your asm.

Comment: What you're saying is that it crashes because I changed the value of r4 to something a higher level function does not expect, and the program crashes when my function has returned. Correct?

Answer (score 7):

According to APCS, **R4** is one of the registers which you must preserve. If you need to use it, then store it on the stack on entry, and pop it off again on exit. There are some registers, such as **R0-R3**, which are scratch registers; you are allowed to corrupt these inside your routine without preserving them.

[See the docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/ch06s02s01.html) for a description of which registers you must preserve and restore before returning from your routine.

> **v1-v8, [f4-f7]**
>
> These are used as register variables. They must be preserved by called functions.

**v1** is the APCS alternative name for **R4**.

Comment: It's all true, but the fact that it has to be preserved does not explain the crash. I updated my answer, please have a look.